# Add custom bool column where data is calculated based on values from linked entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, case

I have 2 tables: `Entity` and `EntityItem`.

`EntityItems` table has a `Reason` column which is nullable enum.

I'm trying to write a view that would return some `Entitity`s columns and additionally a boolean column that states whether all corresponding `EntityItem.Reason` have a non-null value.

The following query returns somewhat what I want:

```
SELECT EntityItem.Id, COUNT(EntityItem.Reason) As Test
FROM EntityItem
GROUP BY EntityItem.ParentEntityId
ORDER BY Test DESC
```

Example output:

```
Id             Test
132189         4
132190         2
132197         1
1              0
2              0
3              0
4              0
5              0
6              0
```

However, when I try to add this to a final query I get duplicated lines for each `EntityItem`

```
SELECT [Entity].[Id],
       ...
        (SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT([EntityItem].[Reason]) FROM [EntityItem] WHERE [EntityItem].[ParentEntityId] = [Entity].[Id]) = 0
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END) AS Test
FROM [Entity]
  ...
  LEFT JOIN [EntityItem] ON [Entity].[Id] = [EntityItem].[ParentEntityId]
```

Example output:

```
Id             Test
1              1
1              1
2              0
2              0
2              0
2              0
3              1
3              1
4              0
```

Question 1: Is my approach correct?

Question 2: Is there a way to remove duplicated lines without `DISTINCT`?

Comment: The first query you've given us would error. You have `Entity.Id` in the `SELECT` and not inside an aggregate function, but the only column you `GROUP BY` is `EntityItem.ParentEntityId`, which isn't even in your `SELECT`.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the highlight, my bad, will update shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second query you need to aggregate *before* joining, for example by using *outer apply* something like:

```
select e.Id, 
  case when i.cnt = 0 then 0 else 1 end as Test
from Entity e
outer apply (
    select Count(Reason) cnt
    from EntityItem i
    where i.ParentEntityId = e.Id
)i;
```

Saying that, since you are always returning a value of 1 if the count is greater than zero you don't actually need to count anything:

```
select e.Id, 
  case when exists (
    select * from EntityItem i 
    where i.ParentEntityId = e.Id
  ) 
  then 1 else 0 end as Test
from Entity e;
```

Comment: Second script is mostly what I was looking for, works like a charm. @Stu, Thanks a bunch!